# Using Ajax in Laravel 4.2 to refresh data being pulled into a table

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

Disclaimer: I'm super new to the programming world, especially with Laravel. I know there are a ton of questions about Laravel and Ajax but I am completely confused by it. Below I have a table pulling the info on users logged in and which page they're on. I have to reload the page for changes, but was wondering if there is a way to do this with ajax.

I have tried many things myself but I think I must be missing something with adding the required step to my routes file. Not sure what else I'd need to add (aside from the ajax portion, too, of course). If someone has the patience to help me and dumb it down a bit I'd be eternally grateful. I'm eager to learn but haven't been able to find a good step-by-step example that fits what I'm trying to do. Thanks!

```
<table style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>User</th>
                    <th>Current Page</th>
                    <th>When</th>
                    <th>IP Address</th>
                    <th>System</th>
                    <th>Browser</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach(Visitor::all() as $visitor)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $visitor->user }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $visitor->page }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $visitor->updated_at->format('h:i A') }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $visitor->ip }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $visitor->platform }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $visitor->browser }}</td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: There are ways to do this with ajax. For someone new to programming this will seem difficult. What you will want to do is have Routes set up that ONLY deliver data. Your javascript will make ajax requests to the Routes that deliver data. Then the javascript will fill the HTML table. To make the data readable, you will want to return your PHP array/object into a JSON object. Simply running Visitors::all()->toJson(); will return you the data in Json

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily have to have different routes for Ajax requests. 
The `Request` class has an `ajax()` method which can tell you whether it is an Ajax request, so that you can amend your response or view accordingly, if that is the type of thing you had in mind?

You could then use your standard routes and have a condition like the following in your controller:

```
if (Request::ajax()) {
    // return Ajax specific view, or do something different for Ajax requests
}
```

Or, similarly, you could even do this at a higher level and use a different view layout for Ajax requests.